# What are some problems in $\mathrm{P}$ with time complexity of high-degree polynomial?

Tags: time-complexity

What are some problems that are in $\mathrm{P}$ but the best known algorithm has a high-degree polynomial ($\ge 3$) time complexity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decision problems in $\mathsf{P}$ without fast algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13202/decision-problems-in-mathsfp-without-fast-algorithms)

Answer (score 2):

**Concrete example**: Thorup's $O(n^{120})$ time algorithm to recognize half-squares of planar bipartite graphs.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.05793

**Parameterized problem**: Some parameterized $NP$-complete problems have arbitrarily large polynomial time algorithms. Like, finding a $k$-clique in a graph can be solved by $\Theta(n^k)$ algorithm. And we do not know how to do much better. There might be some improvement but in general when the parameter increases the degree of the polynomial run-time bound increases also.

Computational geometry problems parameterized with the number of dimensions $d$ can be seen as a special case in this group.

Some other $NP$-complete problems (like Vertex Cover in the comment of kne below) have parameterized version with linear-time algorithm for each parameter value. So, it takes some careful investigations before naming a hard parameterized problems.

Comment: OK, but really we're looking for $\Omega$ bounds, here. For example, we can correctly say that mergesort has running time $O(n^{10^{10}})$.

Comment: From the OP's words "but the best known algorithm has...", so this question is about current status a.k.a. *state of the art*.

Comment: Yes, it's about state of the art. But we're still looking for $\Omega$ bounds. Mergesort is the state of the art and it has running time $O(n^{10^{10}})$.

Comment: The part about parameterized problems is not quite correct. There are NP-complete problems whose parameterized version is in FPT. The classical example is Vertex Cover, which has a linear algorithm for each $k$.

Answer (score 1):

> What are some problems that are in $\mathrm{P}$ but the best known algorithm has a high-degree polynomial ($\ge 3$) time complexity?

Polynomial time always makes me think of nested loops, such that $\ge \operatorname{O}\left(n^3\right)$ looks like "*nest three-or-more loops*".

So, optimizing $f\left(x_0 , \, x_1 , \, \dots , \,x_m \right) ,$ where:

- $f$ is a black-box function;
- each $x_i$ has $n$ distinct values; and
- $m \ge 2 .$

Comment: This is not a decision problem belonging to $\mathrm{P}$. Black-box algorithms are used in other situation when one wants to model a class of algorithms each with the black box replaced by a concrete function. So, you may need to find a hard-enough fuonction $f$ to make your answer helpful.

Comment: @ThinhD.Nguyen Having $f$ being defined as a crypto-hash of the concatenation of the inputs' serializations and then interpreted as a binary integer to be maximized, and the crypto-hash is extended as $n$ and $m$ grow, would seem like an easy example.  However, could you elaborate on the concern about black-box functions?  I mean, it's unclear to me what the concern is.

Answer (score 1):

For an integer $k$, let $P_k$ be the following problem: The input is a program $p$ in your favourite programming language. The question is whether $p$ halts after at most $|p|^k$ steps, where $|p|$ is the input size (the length of the program $p$). Unless the chosen programming language is very unusual, every $P_k$ is decidable in polynomial time; yet for every exponent $e$, there is some $k$ such that $P_k$ requires $\Omega(n^e)$ time. This is an application of the time hierarchy theorem.

The above is an academic example. It is stronger than what you asked for: Not only the best *known* algorithm has a high exponent; all possible algorithms do. An example for a natural problem with a high-ish best-known exponent is primality. There, as far as I know, the exponent is $6$. (To be precise: This is the best known exponent for algorithm. The actual exponent might be lower. In fact, the first estimate for the same algorithm had an exponent of $12$.)