# Examples of higher order algorithms ($\mathcal{O}(n^4)$ or larger)

Tags: time-complexity, p-vs-np

In most computer science cirriculums, students only get to see algorithms that run in very lower time complexities. For example these generally are

1. Constant time $\mathcal{O}(1)$: Ex sum of first $n$ numbers
2. Logarithmic time $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$: Ex binary searching a sorted list
3. Linear time $\mathcal{O}(n)$: Ex Searching an unsorted list
4. LogLinear time $\mathcal{O}(n\log n)$: Ex Merge Sort
5. Quadratic time $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$: Ex Bubble/Insertion/Selection Sort
6. (Rarely) Cubic time $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$: Ex Gaussian Elimination of a Matrix

However it can be shown that
$$
\mathcal{O}(1)\subset \mathcal{O}(\log n)\subset \ldots \subset \mathcal{O}(n^3)\subset \mathcal{O}(n^4)\subset\mathcal{O}(n^5)\subset\ldots\subset \mathcal{O}(n^k)\subset\ldots
$$

so it would be expected that there would be more well known problems that are in higher order time complexity classes, such as $\mathcal{O}(n^8)$.

What are some examples of algorithms that fall into these classes $\mathcal{O}(n^k)$ where $k\geq 4$?

Comment: Look at the [ellipsoid algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Ellipsoid_algorithm,_following_Khachiyan) to solve linear programs.

Comment: [This](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6660/polynomial-time-algorithms-with-huge-exponent-constant/) post on cstheory lists algorithms is a ridiculous polynomial. Somewhat orthogonal, but if you look at the problems that come up you'll find examples of those you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decision problems in $\mathsf{P}$ without fast algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13202/decision-problems-in-mathsfp-without-fast-algorithms)

Comment: You probably want to use the $\Theta(\cdot)$ or $\Omega(\cdot)$ notation. All the algorithms that you have listed run in time $O(n^8)$.

Answer (score 3):

Brute-force algorithms can be considered as a good example to achieve the mentioned running times (i.e. $\Omega(n^4)$).

> Suppose given the sequence $\sigma=\langle a_1,a_2,\dots , a_n\rangle$
> of real numbers, you want to find, if exists   $k$ elements  ($k\geq
>  4$, and $k$ is
> constant ) from $\sigma$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i=0.$$

Obviously, a simple brute-force algorithm for this problem check all $\binom{n}{k}$ subsets of the input and detect whether the elements in at least one of them sum to $0$. If $k$ is a constant then $\binom{n}{k}=\Theta(n^k)$. For example if $k=10$ then the running time of your algorithm is $\Theta(n^{10}).$ Finally, you find algorithm for your desired running time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of $1$-processor gap scheduling of $n$ jobs has time complexity  $O(n^7)$.

The paper is [available here](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/%7Ekirk/cs3150spring2010/p46-demaine.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Most simple example gives nested cycles: we know that, if we want, for example, find similar elements for 2 arrays, then we used 2 nested loops and therefore we have $O(n^2)$ complexity.

Hence, every 4 nested loops gives complexity $O(n^4)$, $k$ nested loops $O(n^k)$.

Another examples [Karmarkar's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karmarkar%27s_algorithm), [AKS primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test)

Comment: The AKS primality test is the example I was going to nominate. The more modern versions are $O(n^{6})$. See https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/complexity12.pdf

Comment: Thanks. Brought link is very interesting.

Comment: At n^6 nanoseconds, you could check a 128 bit integer in a good hour.